# NMinValue , NMaxValue , NMinimize and NMaximize behave poorly for 2-dimensional function unless the constraint is posed as an ImplicitRegion

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am making a plotting function where I need to know the max value the function takes over the given 2D range.  I noticed a difference between the behavior of `NMinValue` , `NMaxValue` , `NMinimize` and `NMaximize` when the constraint is given as a list of constraints versus as an `ImplicitRegion`.

If the region is not far from the actual maximum, they return the same value

```
{NMinValue[{x  Sinc[x]^2 y Sinc[y]^2, -# <= x <= # && -# <= 
       y <= #}, {x, y}],
   NMinValue[{x  Sinc[x]^2 y Sinc[y]^2, {x, y} ∈ 
      ImplicitRegion[-# <= x <= # && -# <= y <= #, {x, y}]}, {x, 
     y}]} & /@ {1, 2}
(* {{-0.501368, -0.501368}, {-0.525062, -0.525062}} *)
```

But if you go farther out, we get numerical instabilities without the `ImplicitRegion`,

```
{NMinValue[{x  Sinc[x]^2 y Sinc[y]^2, -# <= x <= # && -# <= 
       y <= #}, {x, y}],
   NMinValue[{x  Sinc[x]^2 y Sinc[y]^2, {x, y} ∈ 
      ImplicitRegion[-# <= x <= # && -# <= y <= #, {x, y}]}, {x, 
     y}]} & /@ Range[3, 10]
(* {{0.0000440668, -0.525062}, {3.84151*10^-34, -0.525062}, 
{-0.525062, -0.525062}, {-0.155546, -0.525062}, {-0.0446807, -0.525062}, {6.0828*10^-34, -0.525062}, {-0.525062, -0.525062}, 
{-0.0460792, -0.525062}} *)
```

Why is this?  I can see the same behavior with the other functions listed in the post title.  Is this a bug?  Is there something special about the sinc^2 function?  If I change the symmetry, and take away the linear parts of the function, i.e. find the minimum/maximum of `Sinc[x]^2 Sinc[y]^2`, there are no problems.

Comment: Checking the `x` and `y` variables of the `NMinimize` output shows that, with the list of constraints, the default method may get stuck to a stationary point with $y=\pi$ ($sinc(\pi)=0$). Changing the method parameters, e.g., as `NMinimize[{x Sinc[x]^2 y Sinc[y]^2, -# <= x <= # && -# <= y <= #}, {x, y}, Method -> {"NelderMead", "InitialPoints" -> Flatten[Outer[List, Range[-#, #, 1], Range[-#, #, 1]], 1]}] & /@Range[3, 10]` does manage to find the global minimum in all cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is because the `Automatic` method can't find the global min value. A different method can provide a better answer:

```
f = x Sinc[x]^2 y Sinc[y]^2;
methods = {"NelderMead", "RandomSearch", "DifferentialEvolution"};
range = Range[1, 10];

solutions = 
  Transpose[
    Map[
      {NMinValue[{f, 
          -#[[2]] <= x <= #[[2]] && -#[[2]] <= y <= #[[2]]
        }, {x, y}, Method -> #[[1]]],
        NMinValue[{f, 
          {x, y} \[Element] ImplicitRegion[-#[[2]] <= x <= #[[2]] && -#[[2]] <= y <= #[[2]], {x, y}]
        }, {x, y}, Method -> #[[1]]]} &, #]
  ] & /@ Outer[List, methods, range];
```

The solutions of each method are the same with or without the `ImplicitRegion` definition for the constraints:

```
In[1]:= AllTrue[solutions, #[[1]] == #[[2]] &]

Out[1]= True
```