# Create a nonlinear color function

Tags: plotting, color

I'm doing density plots in **Mathematica** where I mostly plot **Wigner functions**.

The main objective when plotting a Wigner function is to demonstrate that the underlying state is nonclassical, as indicated by negative values in the Wigner function. Therefore I want to make these negative values stand out in the plot.

To demonstrate this, I've plotted the Wigner function of an even cat state

[image: cat state]

which was generated using the following **code**

```
(* Plots the Wigner function of an even Cat State *)
α = Sqrt[
  16];
Wigner[x_, y_] := 
  1/(π Sqrt[
    1 + Exp[-2 α^2]]) (Exp[-2 (x - α)^2 - 2 y^2] + 
     Exp[-2 (x + α)^2 - 2 y^2] + 
     2 Exp[-2 x^2 - 2 y^2]*Cos[4 y α]);

DensityPlot[Wigner[x, y], {x, -6, 6}, {y, -2, 2},
    PlotRange -> All,
    ColorFunction -> "LightTemperatureMap",
    PlotLegends -> Placed[
    BarLegend[
        {"LightTemperatureMap", {-.5, .5}},
        LegendMargins -> {{26, 20}, {-15, 0}},
        LegendMarkerSize -> {475, 30}],
    Above],
    ImagePadding -> {{45, 20}, {45, 10}},
    PlotRangePadding -> None,
    ImageSize -> {600, 200},
    AspectRatio -> Automatic,
    FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"},
    FrameTicks -> {{{-2, 0, 2}, None}, {Table[-6 + 2 i, {i, 0, 6}], 
    None}},
    FrameStyle -> Black,
    FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 14],
    LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, 14},
    PlotPoints -> 50
 ]
```

As you can see in the figure above, it's difficult to distinguish positive and negative values around the zero value.

All of the color functions that I've found in Mathematica are linear colormaps where small negative values tend to be near the same color as the zero values, and are thus hidden. I'm looking for a **nonlinear** color function that colors all negative values differently than positive or zero values

See for example the right figure down below
[image: wigner colormap]

Comment: How about something like CoolColorN[ z_ ] := RGBColor[z^3, 1 - z^3, 1]; ContourPlot[Sin[x y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> CoolColor]

Comment: @Lotus I still want better distinction between the positive and negative values, but I think you're on to something.

Comment: I think you should be able to modify the function however you want.

Comment: I recommend looking up the documentation for `ColorFunction`, `ColorData` and `ColorFunctionScaling`.

Comment: You might find the answers here to be useful:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102132/9490

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want abrupt changes in color, `Piecewise` seems more appropriate.

```
colorWig[z_] := Piecewise[{{GrayLevel[1 - z], 0 < z < 1},
                           {Hue[.3, 1, 1 + z], -1 < z < 0}}]

DensityPlot[Sin[x y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> colorWig, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: This seems to be it! Thank you!

Comment: @Turbotanten You're welcome. Some trial and error might be necessary to remap my sample function to the range of values your function takes. I'd suggest waiting for a while until accepting this answer to see if someone comes up with something better. Many engaged users that have more time on their hands than I do currently create truly stunning works here.

Answer (score 8):

A useful trick for using color functions to distinguish signs is to preprocess with `LogisticSigmoid[]`, which maps $(-\infty,\infty)$ to $(0,1)$. Applied to the OP's example:

```
DensityPlot[Wigner[x, y], {x, -6, 6}, {y, -2, 2}, 
            AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
            ColorFunction -> (ColorData["LightTemperatureMap", LogisticSigmoid[20 #]] &),
            ColorFunctionScaling -> False, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
            FrameTicks -> {{{-2, 0, 2}, None}, {Table[-6 + 2 i, {i, 0, 6}], None}},
            FrameStyle -> Black, FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 14], 
            ImagePadding -> {{45, 20}, {45, 10}}, ImageSize -> {600, 200}, 
            LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, 14}, 
            PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[Automatic,
                                            LegendMargins -> {{26, 20}, {-15, 0}},
                                            LegendMarkerSize -> {475, 30}], Above],
            PlotPoints -> 75, PlotRange -> All, PlotRangePadding -> None]
```

[image: Wigner function colored by sign]

Personally, I prefer using `"ThermometerColors"`:

[image: different coloring]

Comment: Wow this looks really good!

Answer (score 5):

```
 colorWig[z_] := 
     Which[-1 < z <= 0, ColorData["DeepSeaColors"][Rescale[z, {-1, 0}]], 
      0 <= z < 1, ColorData["AvocadoColors"][Rescale[z, {0, 1}]]]
    DensityPlot[Sin[x y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
     ColorFunction -> colorWig, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
     PlotPoints -> 50, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Reverse `AvocadoColors`

```
colorWig[z_] := 
 Which[-1 < z <= 0, ColorData["DeepSeaColors"][Rescale[z, {-1, 0}]], 
  0 <= z < 1, 
  ColorData[{"AvocadoColors", "Reverse"}][Rescale[z, {0, 1}]]]
```

[image]

```
NMaximize[{Wigner[x, y], -6 <= x <= 6, -2 <= y <= 2}, {x, y}, 
 Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]
```

> {0.63662, {x -> 0., y -> 0.}}

```
NMinimize[{Wigner[x, y], -6 <= x <= 6, -2 <= y <= 2}, {x, y}, 
 Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]
```

> {-0.590076, {x -> 8.73424*10^-32, y -> 0.193331}}

So we are safe to choose range `[-0.6,0.64]`

```
  colorWig[z_] := 
 Which[-0.6 < z <= 0, 
  ColorData[{"DeepSeaColors", "Reverse"}][Rescale[z, {-0.6, 0}]], 
  0 <= z < 0.65, ColorData["AvocadoColors"][Rescale[z, {0, 0.65}]]]
DensityPlot[Wigner[x, y], {x, -6, 6}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> All, 
 ColorFunction -> colorWig, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMargins -> {{26, 20}, {-15, 0}}, 
    LegendMarkerSize -> {475, 30}], Above], 
 ImagePadding -> {{45, 20}, {45, 10}}, PlotRangePadding -> None, 
 ImageSize -> {600, 200}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, FrameStyle -> Black, 
 FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 14], 
 LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, 14}, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Blue, White,Red}, (π*#+1)/2]&)
```

This is a good color scheme for plotting Wigner distributions. Taken from ["Using Mathematica for Quantum Mechanics: A Student's Manual"](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.1403.7050)

Answer (score 0):

Old Thread, but I had to do a similar thing and did it in a simpler way. Create the color function like this:

```
MyColorFunction =
  Function[
    x,
    Blend[{
      {0.500, Hue[000/360, 0.75, 0.75]},
      {0.750, Hue[030/360, 0.75, 0.75]},
      {1.000, Hue[060/360, 0.75, 0.75]},
      {1.125, Hue[120/360, 0.75, 0.75]},
      {1.250, Hue[180/360, 0.75, 0.75]},
      {1.375, Hue[240/360, 0.75, 0.75]},
      {1.500, Hue[300/360, 0.75, 0.75]}
      },
      x
    ]
  ];
```

The `0.5, 0.75, 1` are the number values, and the colors next to them are the colors that correspond to those values. When applying the color function to a plot, do it like this:

```
ArrayPlot[
  data,
  ColorFunction -> MyColorFunction,
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False
]
```

Set `ColorFunctionScaling` to `False` so that it uses the number values you assigned to each color.