# How to use MatrixPlot as a DensityPlot?

Tags: plotting, matrix, legending

I have a 1000x1000 matrix the MatrixPlot of which gives this graph:

[image: MatrixPlot of data]

The code is

```
matrixplot1 =  MatrixPlot[data, DataReversed -> {True, False},
PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

Since this matrix is obtained by sampling a set of data with X and Y coordinates in 1000x1000 grid the number in the i-th and j-th row and column indicates the number of occurrences between i-1 and j-1.

I would like to have the data on the Log10 scale and on the 0-1 interval for both X and Y axes.
For these reasons I did the following:

1. I transformed the matrix in a {x,y,z} list as follows

```
densityData =   Flatten[ParallelTable[{(j - 0.5)/1000, (i - 0.5)/1000,
data[[i, j]]}, {i, 1, 1000}, {j, 1, 1000}], 1];
```

2. Then I used the DensityListPlot function:

```
graphDensityPlotLog = 
  ListDensityPlot[densityData,
   PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> 0.4*imagesize],
   ScalingFunctions -> "Log10",
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black],
   ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"SunsetColors", "Reverse"}],
   FrameLabel -> {"Quantity X", "Quantity Y"},
   FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 1.1*fontsize],
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 1.3*fontsize],
   PlotRangePadding -> 0,
   ImageSize -> imagesize];
```

The result is
[image: Result of the ListDensityPlot]

Because of the interpolation, there are colored bands in zones that are without any data.
So I tried to obtain the same graph directly by the MatrixPlot with the following code:

```
log10Mod[x_] := If[x == 0, 0, Log10[x]];
log10Mod /@ {0, 1, 2, 3}

graphDensityPlotLog2 = 
 MatrixPlot[data, DataReversed -> {True, False},
  FrameLabel -> {"Quantity X", "Quantity Y"},
  PlotRange -> {{1, 550}, {1, 1000}},
  PlotRangePadding -> 20,
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black],
  FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 1.1*fontsize],
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 1.3*fontsize],
  ImageSize -> imagesize,
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"SunsetColors", "Reverse"}][
      Rescale[log10Mod[#], log10Mod /@ {0, 200}]] &),
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[BarLegend[{(ColorData[{"SunsetColors", "Reverse"}][
         Rescale[#, log10Mod /@ {0, 200}]] &), log10Mod /@ {0, 200}}, 
     LegendMarkerSize -> 400, 
     LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 25, FontFamily -> "Times"]], {1.0,
      0.5}]]
```

The result is the following:
[image: Result of the second try with MatrixPlot]

I am not able to find a way to obtain the graph I obtain with the ListDensityPlot but from the MatrixPlot and without those wrong bands.

Thank you for your help!

Edit: based on the comment I made the following graph

```
fticks[min_, max_, bigstep_, smallstep_] := 
 Table[If[Mod[i, bigstep] == 0, {i + min, 
    ToString[If[IntegerQ[i + min], i + min, (i + min)/1.]], {.01, 
     0}}, {i + min, " ", {.005, 0}}], {i, 0, max - min, smallstep}]
fticksNoText[min_, max_, bigstep_, smallstep_] := 
 Table[If[Mod[i, bigstep] == 0, {i + min, " ", {.01, 0}}, {i + min, 
    " ", {.005, 0}}], {i, 0, max - min, smallstep}]
fticksNoBounds[min_, max_, bigstep_, smallstep_] := 
 Table[If[Mod[i, bigstep] == 0 && i != 0 && 
    i != (max - min), {i + min, 
    ToString[If[IntegerQ[i + min], i + min, (i + min)/1.]], {.01, 
     0}}, {i + min, " ", {.005, 0}}], {i, 0, max - min, smallstep}]
fticksReversed[min_, max_, bigstep_, smallstep_] := 
 Table[If[Mod[i, bigstep] == 0, {i + min, 
    ToString[If[IntegerQ[max - i], max - i, (max - i)/1.]], {.01, 
     0}}, {i + min, " ", {.005, 0}}], {i, 0, max - min, smallstep}]

graphDensityPlotLog3 = 
 MatrixPlot[data, DataReversed -> {True, False},
  FrameLabel -> {"Quantity X", "Quantity Y"},
  PlotRangePadding -> 0,
  DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 0.55}},
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black],
  FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 1.1*fontsize],
  FrameTicks -> {{fticksReversed[0, 1, 1/10, 1/100], 
     fticksNoText[0, 1, 1/10, 1/100]}, {fticksNoBounds[0, 1, 2/10, 
      4/100], fticksNoText[0, 1, 2/10, 4/100]}},
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 1.3*fontsize],
  ImageSize -> imagesize,
  AspectRatio -> 1,
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"SunsetColors", "Reverse"}][
      Rescale[log10Mod[#], log10Mod /@ {0, 200}]] &),
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[BarLegend[{(ColorData[{"SunsetColors", "Reverse"}][
         Rescale[#, log10Mod /@ {0, 200}]] &), log10Mod /@ {0, 200}}, 
     LegendMarkerSize -> 400, 
     LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 25, FontFamily -> "Times"]], {1.0,
      0.5}]]
```

The result is
[image: Result of the third MatrixPlot]

I had to define the ticks in order to put them in a MatrixPlot going from zero to one.

The problem of the legend bar remains to be solved.

Comment: You can try `MatrixPlot[data, DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]` or `MatrixPlot[Log10@data, DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]`?

Comment: Another possibility is `ListDensityPlot[Table[Sin[j^2 + i], {i, 0, Pi, 0.5}, {j, 0, Pi, 0.5}], Mesh -> None, InterpolationOrder -> 0, PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: @kglr adding DataRange solves one problem, thanks.
Doing Log10@data instead gives a plot with strange colors.

Comment: @yarchik using ListDensityPlot in this way does not give the results I search.

Comment: And what is the problem? Can you be more specific?

Comment: @yarchik there are two problems:
1) ListDensityPlot is very slow compared to MatrixPlot (minor problem)
2) The result I obtain by doing what you suggest is the following figure https://imgur.com/a/7bY0QGp (the real problem)

Comment: You can get rid of unwanted areas with e.g. `PlotRange -> {10^-9, 1000}`. To add a log-scale bar, this post is relevant https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102132/how-can-i-make-a-density-plot-or-contour-plot-with-an-arbitrary-nonlinear-scal

Comment: @yarchik I do not understand. In the ListDensityPlot, I can use PlotRange to specify the X and Y axes.
Do you mean that I can also specify the Z(height/color)-axes?
Moreover, when using ListDensityPlot I have no problems with adding the log-scale bar (you can see it in the code for ListDensityPlot in the question). Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, my idea was to specify `PlotRange` for z-values. It could be, for instance, `PlotRange->{All,All,{10^-9, 10}}`. It should cut the unwanted artifacts in your plot. I tested on some artificially created data and it works. But I do not have the original one.

Comment: @yarchik I tried but it does not work