# What is the best way to obtain a numerical probability distribution from a big two-dimensional set of data?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

Let us suppose that I have a set of N points described by x-y couples, i.e., I have a table such that, for example, `table[[4]]={0.234,0.678}`.
For every element of the table, both x and y are comprised between 0 and 1.

The points in the table are not uniformly distributed, but they are a lot, say 10^9, so that doing `ListPlot[table]` simply gives a graph that does not give any information about the actual distribution of the points since they amass.

What is the best way to obtain a numerical distribution graph based on the sample I have?
I want to do an x-y colored graph in which the color of each point is linked to the probability of obtaining a random point around the point in the graph, preferably in the Log10 scale.
If I could plot in this way the numerical Probability Density Function it would be the best thing.

Thank you all for the answers!

Comment: Perhaps look at [`DensityHistogram`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DensityHistogram.html)?

Comment: Look at documentation for  [`EmpiricalDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EmpiricalDistribution.html), [`HistogramDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HistogramDistribution.html), [`SmoothKernelDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SmoothKernelDistribution.html), and [`FindDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindDistribution.html)

Comment: @march thanks, DensityHistogram seems to do what I want but it is extremely slow. I tried with 10^6 point in a 1000x1000 grid and I had to abort because it did not finish to make the calculations.
Moreover, I would like to save the result of this organization of the data. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @BobHanlon I do not understand from the documentation how should I obtain a graph like the one given by DensityHistogram. For reference, I am trying to obtain graphs like in this other question I made https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/214629/how-to-use-matrixplot-as-a-densityplot 
There, I organized the data with a custom function in order to obtain a 1000x1000 matrix, but the problem is that then I have problems with the representation of those data. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do not ask questions in the comments of other questions. Start a new question, show the code for what you have tried and explain what specific problems you are having. Include a reduced representative data set.